# A description about SOCAT

Tags: android, ssh, ssh-tunnel, socat

can anybody describe me SOCAT? in fact what's socat? how can I setting it up? 
I'm trying to make a SSH tunnel in an android project but I found it out that using socat is also necessary in my tunnel, but I don't know what it is!!!

Comment: Where did you find out that using it is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You could start with the [README](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/README).

To be clear, socat is a extended version of [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/).

The [netcat wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) is likely of interest.

> I'm trying to make a SSH tunnel in an android project but I found it out that using socat is also necessary in my tunnel

I'm not entirely convinced that this is true, but your question directly asks about socat.